# Permission Denied when read a local file using Data(contentsOf: URL)

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, uidocumentinteraction, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

The file I'm reading is （`let data = try Data(contentsOf: url) ...`）

```
 url: file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15666F33-0EA8-4F1B-BFBA-634EEE9FC97D/Documents/Attachments/Documents/test.numbers
```

But an error was caught which says `Permission Denied`

This is a file imported using `UIDocumentPicker` with `import` mode and moved to local folder using `FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url, to: newURL)`

The file does exist, and `UIDocumentInteractionController` does open it successfully with the same url.

I guess the access control of the original file is copied by `UIDocumentPicker` as well. But I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask Google about sandbox.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show more code

Comment: You could try to copy the file instead of moving it. his will change the permissions.

Comment: @ElTomato It seems not a sandbox issue and all the results googled are about macOS sandbox. I've googled a lot including Apple developer forum.

Comment: In iOS, every app you develop is sandboxed.  So they don't even talk about sandbox perse.  In macOS, they have options of sandboxing or not sandboxing the application.

Comment: See the difference between macOS and iOS under Capabilities.